# Neither image gap nor image alignment is working in phpword

Tags: php, phpword

I have two images in the same row and I want to put some space between them.

[image]

Currently nothing is working even I try hard to search for solution.

Here is the code:

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection($PidPageSettings);
$table = $section->addTable();

$logo = 'pearson1' . $clientid . ".png";
$logo2 = 'genesis2' . $clientid . ".png";

// $table = $section->addTable();
// $table->addRow();
// $cell = $table->addCell(20000, array('bgColor' => 'ffffff'));

$table = $section->addTable();
$table->addRow();
$table->addCell(2000, $cellRowSpan)->addImage('pearson1.png',array('width' => '70','height' => '70','valign' => 'left'));
$table->addCell(2000, $cellRowSpan)->addImage('genesis2.png',array('width' => '120','height' => '40'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use image [margin](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#image) to **adjust space** between the two images.

> marginLeft. Left margin in inches, can be negative.
>
> marginTop. Top margin in inches, can be negative.

In the example is 20, tweak it depending on your needs.

Note about **vertical alignment**:

> valign. Vertical alignment, top, center, both, bottom.

So *left* is not valid for *valign*. Moreover it is for cell, not for image.
valign setting should be included in your `$cellRowSpan` like:
`$cellRowSpan = array('valign' => 'center');`

Set **alignment for image** like: `\PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::CENTER` as in [this example](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_13_Images.php)

Tweak width and height if you want to **adjust dimension** of images.

> height. Height in pt.
>
> width. Width in pt.

**For example** (adjust parameters for your needs):

```
$table->addCell(2000, $cellRowSpan)->addImage('pearson1.png',array('width' => 70,'height' => 70, 'marginLeft' => 20, 'alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::CENTER));
$table->addCell(2000, $cellRowSpan)->addImage('genesis2.png',array('width' => 210,'height' => 70, 'marginLeft' => 20, 'alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::CENTER));
```

Comment: thanks buddy but it gives an error of this -   Uncaught Error: Call to a member function addCell() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\report edite\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Element\Table.php:85 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\report edite\sreport_new_I0027.php(305): PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Table->addCell(2000, NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\report edite\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Element\Table.php on line 85

Comment: your new code is not giving error now but also it is not helping to align it or reduce gap also. :(

Comment: Thanks for the help i really appreciate it brother , may i know have you tried it practically because this is not working for me at all :/ i guess there might be some issues from my side which i am unable to track.

Comment: What's in the variable `$cellRowSpan` ?

Comment: Here you find the examples that i have read when used this library https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/master/samples